# How to see deleted messages in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How do I find old messages in Messenger? I don't know how to refresh deleted messages on Facebook messenger app.

Comment: Are you using the web interface or a native app? If the latter, I'm afraid your question is off topic here. Questions about Facebook on Web Apps should be almost exclusively about working with the web interface of Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge deleted messages can't recovered.

But you can give a try by **downloading a copy of your Facebook data** (you will get this option under **Settings** -> **General Account Settings**). If you would have been lucky and Facebook had backed-up data before you deleted, may be you will get all those messages.

Comment: Dear downvoter, may I know the reason for downvote?